# How can i make download manager overwrite an exisiting file instead of renaming the file in android

Tags: android

I have a database file which is on the sdcard and now when a new database file is downloaded i need it to overwrite the old one instead of renaming it
here is my downloading code. The download code is working perfectly..

```
  public void startDownload() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Database. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    Uri uri=Uri.parse(file_url);

    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File ADirectory = new File(baseDir +"/test");
    ADirectory.mkdirs();

    lastDownload=
      mgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                  .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                                          DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                  .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                  .setTitle(" Database File")
                  .setDescription("Please wait....test Database downloading.")
                  .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/test", "/testing"));

    pDialog.show();
    //v.setEnabled(false);
   // findViewById(R.id.query).setEnabled(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

when you're submitting the file to the download manager check if the file already exists. then delete it.

```
private boolean isFileExists(String filename){

    File folder1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + filename);
    return folder1.exists();


}

private boolean deleteFile( String filename){

    File folder1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + filename);
    return folder1.delete();


}
```

Comment: If there is no internet connection at the moment, the download process will be queued. In this case, this code won't work. It is necessary to check the internet connection and not request downloads if there is no connection.

Comment: @MahmutK. i think you can download to "temp" folder, after the download finished, move it to the real directory