# How to open a save-file-dialog in Android to select a target for the download-manager?

Tags: android

I'm working on a functionality for an Android-Application, which downloads a file from a local server using the Android Download-Manager. Up to now I easily download the file to the downloads directory by using

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,filename);
```

Now I would like to let the user choose the target including the filename. Therefore I use the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`Intent:

```
void pickTargetFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent()
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
            .setType("image/jpeg");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a target to save the file"), SAVE_FILE_CODE);
}
```

But when I now use the resulting path in the download-manager it doesn't write the data in the created file but creates a new one named e.g. filename-1.jpeg when filename.jpeg was created by the File-Create-Dialog. 
Either I would like the download-manager to write into the previously created file or use another dialog to choose a target for the download-manager but not creating the file by the dialog.

Does someone know an easy way to archive this?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the file first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362659/how-can-i-make-download-manager-overwrite-an-exisiting-file-instead-of-renaming

Comment: Thanks for that hint! I already found this post before and also tried it, but it didn't worked for some reason... I don't know why, but now it works perfectly. So thanks again!

Comment: I have to add, that this solution still seams to be not perfect. Because I like to ask the user, whether to overwrite an existing file. But the create-document-dialog directly creates a new file if none exists with the entered filename. So when I check whether the file exists before asking the user for permission to overwrite, File#exists() is always true. As a workaround I now check weather the size of the file is not 0 instead. 
I would still prefer a clean solution if someone knows one...

Comment: `File#exists() `. How do you use the `File` class for a `DocumentFile` instance?

Comment: I'm creating a File-Object. I extract the path from the content-Uri and build a File-Object with `final java.io.File f = new java.io.File(path);`

Comment: That looks like a wrong approch to me. You will find that in many occasions you will not be able to extract a file path from a content uri obtained by ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. And if you can the user could have chosen a location unwritable for the File class. I now also wonder what you give to the download manager. That path or the original uri? To handle such files you should use DocumentFile.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that hint. But passing the content-Uri resulting of the DocumentFile#getUri() results in an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file URI: content://com.android....`

Up to now I pass the Uri I get when calling `File#getUri()`, which is an file-Uri.

Comment: Try to pick a location on a micro SD card. On modern Android versions they are unwritable with file uris. Please report.

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I choose an folder on an micro-sd-card the save-button in the create-document-dialog is gray.

Comment: That's not what i suggested. Completely different. You should be able to create files on it with SAF. But only using the deduced file uri would not work for download manager. That's what i said.

Comment: Okay, sorry. But finally I don't understand what you suggest me to do to solve my problem.